# Python browsermob proxy with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, browsermob

I'm trying to import the Google HAR file, but this code I wrote gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'ProxyManger' object has no attribute '_ProxyManger__server'. Did you mean: '_ProxyManger__BMP'?
```

My codes:

```
import pprint
import time

from browsermobproxy import Server
from selenium import webdriver

class ProxyManger:

    __BMP = "C:/Users/Ender/Desktop/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy.bat"

    def __int__(self):
        self.__server = Server(ProxyManger.__BMP)
        self.__client = None

    def start_server(self):
        self.__server.start()
        return self.__server

    def start_client(self):

        self.__client = self.__server.create_proxy(params={"trustAllServers": "true"})
        return self.__client

    @property
    def client(self):
        return self.__client
    @property
    def server(self):
        return self.__server
if "__main__" == __name__:
    proxy = ProxyManger()
    server = proxy.start_server()
    client = proxy.start_client()
    client.new_har("google.com")
    print(client.proxy)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--proxy-server={}".format(client.proxy))
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    time.sleep(3)

    pprint.pprint(client.har)
    server.stop()
```

I don't understand where I went wrong, what is the source of the problem and how do I need to fix it? I would be glad if you help. have a nice day

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028604/cant-capture-har-using-python-selenium-script-with-browsermob-proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__init__` function is written wrong, you have `__int__` it's suposed to be `__init__`
since it does't enter the init function it does't create the _server atribute

Comment: It worked, thanks, but the chrome window shows "Your connection is not private", how do I fix it?

Comment: Thanks i did it, i forgot add certificates on chrome.